# Backbone - history.back() reloads page if .navigate({replace: true}) is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, navigation, browser-history

I have this weird problem with Backbone navigation. I read a lot of posts and can't find anything that relates to my issue.

So here is the situation: lets say we have pages: A, B and C.
B is the edit page and I don't want to include it in history.

If the user is on page A, goes to B, and then to C. If he clicks the back button, he should be redirected to A.

So, to make it work, I listen to all click events on  elements, intercept them, and call the Backbone.history.navigate() method. Also I check the current url, if it is B, I pass the {replace: true} parameter to navigate(), so that B is omitted from history.

Basically it works, B is omitted from history. Only in case when B is skipped the page reloads, doesn't just change the view. If non of the routes are skipped, it works without reloading.

So, for example:

- if I go from A to B, click "back", browser goes back to A, without reloading, it replaces the view with a slide animation
- if I go from A to B and then to C, click "back", browser goes to A, but reloads the page. So I don' see the slide animation, but a full reload with a flashing blank page.

I'm not using pushState. Currently testing on Chrome.

Any advice would be welcome. I'm stuck on this for a few hours. Whatever I tried resulted in the same behavior. I tried enabling pushState, no change.

Comment: I know it is hard to reproduce something like that with code but is it too much to make a simple fiddle for that? I would say the problem maybe is with the functions that is initiated when the router for page A is encountered. Maybe you check if the view corresponds to page B then make a sliding animation and you are not handling the other situation if the page is C?

Comment: It is not that simple. Animations are done with jQuery Mobile, routing with Backbone... I would have to make a whole mini app for the fiddle. I was hoping someone stumbled on this before and knows the problem. I'll make a fiddle later if no one has an answer. There isn't any view specific checking. Views are created from router methods, they all use the same method for view replacement. The only "special" logic is when moving from B to C, when the replace:true parameter is passed. Everything else if identical in all routes

Comment: @ZolaKt I'm seeing the same thing happen in a Backbone app I'm building. I'll put together a little example for you.

Comment: I tried to place a link to an example into the original question, but it looks like that didn't work. Here's the example anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/niaconis/AV6V6/3/ @AhmadAlfy does this help with diagnosis?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this too, in chrome 35.0.1916.114 m, but don't have enough points to comment :)
@codefox421, I can recreate the effect in your fiddle by modifying
the routeViewB handler like this:

```
   routeViewB: function routeViewB() {
        this.navigate("xxx",{trigger:false,replace:true} );
        $('body>*').detach();
        $('body').append( app.viewB.$el );
    },
```

now after visiting B, clicking back will reload the page :(

I also found reports of a remarkably similar problem here:
https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/513

would love a workaround/fix. atm I'm stumped.

** I just updated to latest chrome and the problem is fixed.